# How to detect picklist change in workflow criteria

Tags: workflow, picklist

I have custom picklist field on account, let us say follow_up_days__c.

I want to create a workflow whenever the field follow_up_days__c is changed, sfdc should send email to email of account

I am trying to use ischanged() in workflow. but help doc saying it is not supporting picklist field, but only for multi-picklist field.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `PRIORVALUE` to check for the value of picklist change. For example

```
OR(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(MyField__c), "Old val1"),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(MyField__c), "Old val2")
)

&&

OR(
ISPICKVAL(MyField__c, "New Val1"),
ISPICKVAL(MyField__c, "New Val2")
)
```